# Binding a List in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Model object with this property:

```
private List<MultipartFile> files;
```

but when I bind them in the template:

```
<input type="file" id="file1" class="form-control" th:field="*{files[0]}" name="files" accept=".gif, .jpg, .png, .jpeg" />
<input type="file" id="file2" class="form-control" th:field="*{files[1]}" name="files" accept=".gif, .jpg, .png, .jpeg" />
```

I have this error:

```
    ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'files' of bean class [com.domain.frontend.UserPayload]: Could not instantiate property type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile] to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.newValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:919)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.growCollectionIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:785)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:654)
    ... 96 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile.<init>()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem not too long ago. I solved it by wrapping the List<> object in a Data Transfer Object then modifying the List<> as a field instead of the object itself. Here is your solution:
DTO class

```
public class FileDTO {

    private List<File> files;

    public FileDTO() {
        files = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<File> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setFiles(List<File> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }
}
```

thymeleaf view:

```
<form action="/example" th:object="${dto}">
    <input type="file" th:each="file, itemStat : *{files}" th:id="${'file' + ${itemStat.index}}"
           th:field="*{files[__${itemStat.index}__]}" name="files" accept=".gif, .jpg, .png, .jpeg">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Sorry if that was a little much to sort through. But the idea is that the `List<>` has to be a field not the form backing object itself then to iterate over the List<> field you can use the loop shown.